# Rest Service on WSO2 ESB API with a Mal Formed XML request

Tags: rest, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have created an api proxy to call my rest service, but when I send in a Mal formed XML request, I only receive an HTTP status code 202.

I have coded my service to handle this mal formed xml, and I just want the ESB to pass through the request.

Here is the code to my ESB API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="myApi" context="/restService">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://myserver/MyRestService"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the Content-Type header in request?

Comment: Yes application/xml

Answer (score 2):

In this case, ESB should be able to successfully send the message to the backend. By [enabling wire logs](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html) you can make sure message sending correctly to the backend.
If you are not expecting any response from your backend, Please set out_only property in your inseqeunce

Comment: The message never gets to the back